# Will Office 365 Home or Personal open old .doc, .dot and .xls files?

Tags: windows-10, office365, microsoft-office-2016, microsoft-word-2016

I currently have a cheap Office-365 Online subscription, which lets me use online versions of a.o. Word and Excel.

*(So far my experience with the online versions has been terrible; I've never wasted so much time trying to make the smallest of edits to simple documents.)*

My main problem is that I cannot open older Office documents or templates. In the "open file" menu all the .doc and .dot files in my DropBox and OneDrive are greyed out, and only the .docx files can be opened.

*(I don't think this is related to Windows 10's File Block settings, since these are meant for installed programmes and should have no effect on in-browser apps.)*

Before I upgrade to an installed version of Office-365, I'd like to make sure that this will solve the problem. Can anyone confirm that the installed versions of Word and Excel that you get with an Office-365 Home or Personal subscription do indeed open older .doc, .dot and .xls files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am currently subscribed to **Office 365 Home** with Office 2016 installed (on a Windows 10 Pro machine), and I can attest that the legacy capabilities still work. I regularly open old `.doc` and `.xls` files that I previously created many years ago with Office 2003.

Microsoft also has references online that list the file formats supported within Word, Excel, and PowerPoint, including all three that you mentioned.  Although the following list specifically emphasizes Office 2013, the same principles should apply for Office 2016:

[File format reference for Word 2013, PowerPoint 2013, and Excel 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd797428.aspx)

Comment: sorry, you're right.

Comment: No problem, just a minor misunderstanding.  Thanks for the follow-up.

Comment: Thanks. I had spent some time on the Microsoft website but had not found a clearly worded answer.